# Hensel's Lemma Argument

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Let $f(X)$ be a polynomial with integer coefficients.
Let $p$ be a prime number. Recall that

ord$_p$$ : Z → N∪ {∞}$

is the function such that

ord$_p(0) = ∞$, $n ≡ 0 ($mod $p^{ord_p(n)})$, and $n\not\equiv 0 ($mod $p^{1+ordp(n)})$

for every non-zero integer $n$.

Suppose that $a_0$ is an integer such that

$f'(a_0)\not\equiv 0$ and 
$2$ord$_p(f'(a_0)) < $ord$_p(f(a_0))$.
Here $f'(X)$ is the derivative of the polynomial $f(X)$. Show that for every positive integer $n$, there
exists an integer $b_n$ such that

$f(b_n) ≡ 0 ($mod$ p^n)$ and ord$_p(b_n −a_0) ≥ $ord$_p(f(a_0))−$ord$_p(f'(a_0)) > 0$.

How should I approach this?

Comment: Haven't done Hensel's lemma-like arguments for awhile, but as I recall the proof involved replacing the indeterminate $X$ with a sum of two indeterminates $X+Y$, and expanding the polynomial $f(X+Y)$, much like a Taylor series expansion.

Comment: If I just prove Hensel's lemma, does that solve it? I have a pdf open that explains Hensel's lemma and it has something like that with Taylor series expansion in it but I wasn't sure

Comment: Thank you for the input though

Comment: @Jimm I don't think Hensel's lemma implies this; in fact Hensel's lemma is a special case of this where $\mathrm{ord}_p(f'(a_0))=0$.

Answer (score 0):

By using binomial expansion, we have $f(y)=f(x)+f'(x)(y-x)+g(x)(y-x)^2$ for some integer polynomial $g$.

We prove the statement by induction on $n$. Let $k=\mathrm{ord}_p(f(a_0))>0$ and $l=\mathrm{ord}_p(f'(a_0))$. The statement holds for $n\leq k$ with $b_n=a_0$. Suppose $n\geq k$ and we already have $b_n$. Note that
$$
  \mathrm{ord}_p(b_n-a_0)\geq k-l>l,
$$
so $b_n\equiv a_0\pmod{p^{l+1}}$. Thus $f'(b_n)\equiv f'(a_0)\pmod{p^{l+1}}$, so $\mathrm{ord}_pf'(b_n)=l$. Let $c$ be the inverse of $f'(b_n)/p^l\pmod{p}$, and let $d=-cf(b_n)/p^n$ (which is an integer since $p^n|f(b_n)$). Let
$$
  b_{n+1}=b_n+dp^{n-l}.
$$
Since $n\geq k$ and $p^{k-l}|b_n-a_0$, we have $p^{k-l}|b_{n+1}-a_0$. Finally
\begin{eqnarray*}
  f(b_{n+1})&=&f(b_n)+df'(b_n)p^{n-l}+d^2g(b_n)p^{2n-2l}\\
    &=&f(b_n)(1-cf'(b_n)/p^l)+d^2g(b_n)p^{2n-2l}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now $p|1-cf'(b_n)/p^l$ and $2n-2l\geq n+k-2l>n$, so $p^{n+1}|f(b_{n+1})$ as required.